# How to access an image inside an IFRAME tag from code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, iframe, file-upload

I have Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx page in this page there is an iframe tag which refers to a page "OpenDialog.aspx" 
 this page is in my project and i created it to open a dialog file and preview an image to user i used httphandler file named "ImageRequestHandler.ashx" to preview image by changing src attribute of image control "ImgPrv" to "ImageRequestHandler.ashx" this works fine user can open a file and preview it before commit save button 
 i also mentioned that i used a session to store the data of image file in byte arrays and save this byte array to db these are all about the time that user wants to insert new data to DB.
but my problem is that the time which user wants to see data which has been stored before in db
i have a radgrid in Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx and i want that when user clicks in a row of radgrid then the image inside IFRAME changed to appropriate image from db, 
 i can read byte array of image from Db but i don't know how to set it to the image i also can set the session variable that my httphandler works with but i don't know how to set imageUrl of image inside Iframe tag.

i also have done it with a simple image control in the page but i want to change image inside iframe is it possible or not> if it is possible how can i do it.....

in my aspx file Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx

```
<iframe id ="OpenDialogControl" runat="server"
 src = "OpenDialog.aspx" frameborder="0"  name="Iframe1"  
 scrolling="no" height="110px" width="100px"></iframe>
```

in code behind Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx

```
 byte[] SelectedImage;
 SelectedImage = (byte[])(ImageArray.Rows[selectedReceiptIndex][8]); //Image Array ->Grid Data table
 Session["SessionImage"] = SelectedImage;
 Random random = new Random();
 ShowImage0.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ImageRequestHandler.ashx?randomno="+ random.Next(0,1000).ToString());

        //I have tried following codes to access ImagePrv Element in Iframe1 but i couldn't
        //var image = OpenDialogControl.FindControl("ImagePrv") as Image;
```

in my aspx file Opendialog

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function getRandomNumber() {
            var randomnumber = Math.random(10000);
            return randomnumber;
        }

        function OnClientAsyncFileUploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var handlerPage = '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ImageRequestHandler.ashx")%>';
            var queryString = '?randomno=' + getRandomNumber();
            var src = handlerPage + queryString;
            var clientId = 'ImagePrv';
            document.getElementById(clientId).setAttribute("src", src);
        }
        function showName(object) {

            document.write(object.id);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body style= "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:0px; ">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style= "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:0px; ">
    <div style= "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:0px; ">
        <img alt="" src="" id ="ImagePrv" runat="server"
            style= "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:0px; height: 120px; width: 110px;"/> </div>
            <br /><br /><br />
    <div style= "visibility:visible">
        <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" ThrobberID="tid1" 
            onclientuploadcomplete="OnClientAsyncFileUploadComplete" />
    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in open dialog code behind

```
 public partial class OpenDialog : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public static readonly string STORED_IMAGE = "SessionImage";
    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile;

            byte[] data = ReadFile(file);
            Session[STORED_IMAGE] = data;
        }
    }
    private byte[] ReadFile(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        byte[] data = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);
        return data;

    }

}
```

i have got a httphandler with the name ImageRequestHandler.ashx

code behind of ImageRequestHandler.ashx

```
public class ImageRequestHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();

           if (context.Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
            //if (context.Request.Cookies.Count != 0)
            {
                var storedImage = context.Session[OpenDialog.STORED_IMAGE] as byte[];
                if (storedImage != null)
                {
                    Image image = GetImage(storedImage);
                    if (image != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Image GetImage(byte[] storedImage)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(storedImage);
            return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

I hope so if there is any solution with javascript i have tried document.geteleme.... but it does not work!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This would be clearer if you could break your description out in separate paragraphs.  Just my two cents.

Comment: Wouldn't it work just to reload the iFrame?  Your iFrame page would reload and could access the information in session.

Comment: Would You mind Tell me more about it. i want to access an image inside iframe i know how to show the image but icant access to image in side iframe i just want to set src attribute to my httphandler i dont kno how to describe it more clear than this...

Comment: Your second code example:  is that the code behind for OpenDialog.aspx, or for Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx?

Comment: It's code of Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx i edit the question to declare it more

Comment: OK, I've looked at your code and nothing jumps out at me as being wrong.  So it comes down to debugging.  Does the variable `handlerPage` get the right value?  Does `ImageRequestHandler` ever get called?  In `ImageRequestHandler`, if it gets called, is there a value in Session when it looks for it?  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your iframe is embedded in Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx, you need to think of Frm_MngAddGoodsGrp.aspx and OpenDialog.aspx as separate pages (which they are).  You cannot directly change what appears in one page from the code-behind of another.

That said, there are a couple of ways that a page hosting an iframe can communicate with the page hosted in the iframe:

1. If the pages are from the same application, they can share session state.  You can put something (such as an image id) in session in the parent page and have the child page access it.
2. Because the iframe's `src` attribute can be set in the parent page, you can pass values in the query string to the child page.
3. You can force the iframe to reload, thus forcing the child page to go through its life cycle.  If you have changed values in session state or in the child page query string, they can be accessed again.

Assuming that your parent page knows what the id is of the new image, I would set the src attribute of the iFrame to `OpenDialog.aspx?imageId=12345` and have OpenDialog.aspx retrieve the value from its query string and use it to set the `ImageUrl` property of your image control.

Comment: This description tell me that how to pass some thing (parameter) to a page embedded in iframe but algorithm which i used is to using session

Comment: i have done the thing that i want with a simple image in my form but i want to do it to image inside iframe which it's src is set to OpenDialog,

Comment: my parent page knows the byte array of image and sends it to session but there is a button in the page which fires AsyncFileUpload 's brows button click then after fileupload completes on client image handler create a image preview on client inside open dialog page then i want to just do the image preview operations on my parent page by clicking on radgrid row each row has it's own image but i want to just load image after event selected index change of rad grid.Thanks @Ann L. for your attentions

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're saying.  (I appreciate your patience!)  I will look at this and give you a better answer in a few minutes.

Comment: i have done some changes to page load of open dialog and it works fine to me i will tell it in detail to you later Thanks for your attention you provide me a perfect answer. Thanks  **Ann L.**

Comment: if you think this question is useful for others please vote it up